# Resetting a class parameter upon new instance of that class: JS ES6

Tags: javascript, canvas, javascript-objects, es6-class

I am working on creating a game that redraws the canvas every time the player goes to a new "room". While most of the functionality is there, I am having some trouble with the player... although the rest of my room-drawing class Room gets reset and reinitialized with no reference to the previous room, the player square carries across to the next screen and stays in the same place.

My User class:

```
class User {
   constructor(user, x, y, ctx) {
     for (let metric in user) { this[metric] = user[metric]; }
     this.initialX = x;
     this.initialY = y;
     this.ctx = ctx;
     this.move = this.move.bind(this);
     //// various other constructor things...
   }
   //// various other methods
   move(e) {
      //// motion description
      if (this.y - 5 <= 0 {
          init(theRoom.connectingRooms[0], this.x, 550) ///// should create a new box at the last player-x position and y-position 550
          }
       }
    }
```

My Room class:

```
class Room {
    constructor(canv, room, player) {
    for (let key in canv) { this[key] = canv[key]; }
    for (let attr in room) { this[attr] = room[attr]; } 
    this.drawWalls();
    this.player = player; /// adding player to room
  } /// end of constructor
////methods, nothing that affects player
}
```

Initializer:

```
let init = function init(room, x, y) {
  canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas = new CanvasState(canv); 
  player = new User(user, x, y, canvas.ctx); //// it's remembering the last player I set instead of removing the old one & creating a new one
  theRoom = new Room(canvas, room, player);
  window.addEventListener('keydown', theRoom.player.move);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', theRoom.typeInput);
};
```

You can see this [on CodePen here](http://codepen.io/jlr7245/pen/xRQNeK). The relevant lines are 10, 53, 185, & 232.

I'm pretty new to JS and *very* new to the canvas element, so I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake in here somewhere, but I can't seem to spot it.

Comment: Are you passing the same player object to more than one room object?  `this.player` is just a reference to the player object you passed in to the constructor function to begin with, so if you pass a reference to the same player object to more than one room, you end up with multiple rooms having reference to the same player.

Comment: @PMV Oh! You know what, you're right, I am. That helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before overwriting the `player` variable with the new one, you need to remove the key handlers from `window`. Those are still referencing the methods of the old player object, which consequently is drawn every time you move it.

You can use

```
function init(room, x, y) {
  canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas = new CanvasState(canv);

  if (player != null)
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', player.move);
  player = new User(user, x, y, canvas.ctx);
  window.addEventListener('keydown', player.move);

  if (theRoom != null)
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', theRoom.typeInput);
  theRoom = new Room(canvas, room, player);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', theRoom.typeInput);
}
```

Another approach would be to register only one callback that invokes the respective method of the current object (so that you don't need to `.bind` them as well):

```
function init(room, x, y) {
  canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas = new CanvasState(canv);
  player = new User(user, x, y, canvas.ctx);
  theRoom = new Room(canvas, room, player);
}

window.onload = function() {
  init(castleCourtyard, 350, 100);
  window.addEventListener('keyup', e => theRoom.typeInput(e));
  window.addEventListener('keydown', e => player.move(e));
};
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much! I am still having trouble clearing the previous player square [as in this pen](http://codepen.io/jlr7245/pen/zoyzav), but since it doesn't affect the game play much, I'm not worried.